# Import Word to the Mysql Database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question bank in the word file, and I want to import this file into my database,

in my database i have 2 tables
Table 1 -> question
Table 2 -> options

so if I import this file to the database
questions in the word file are stored in the table -> question, and the options of the question  will be stored in the table -> options

maybe someone can solve it please

[This is My Word File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxv0i.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

I was completed once this type of job like explain below:-

Take a look at the screenshot the possible format into MySQL import database 
[image]

So i think first convert word file into csv  format [online](https://convertio.co/doc-csv/)

After that, you can import the CSV file easily to your MySQL database 
https://prnt.sc/hgn272  check screenshot if you are going to import data direct your existing tables

The 2nd way to import word files with coding: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/create_word_excel_csv_files_with_php.php

Thanks

Comment: but if the question have a image, can it be saved to the database?

Comment: You mean inset images into database through word doc file?

Comment: sometimes some question have a picture

Comment: Then the row will be inserted based on directory URL.

Comment: and if the question have a matematic formulas ?

Comment: Then need to create a code into your file like this $interest=0.5;

$amt=$_POST['amount'];
$duration=$_POST['duration']; // duration is in months

$intamt=pow((1+$interest),$duration);

$intamt2=pow((1+$interest),($duration-1));

$installment=($amt*0.5*$intamt)/$intamt2;

echo $installment;  and then final result will insert to database